# How can I call a function stored in one object on another object by name?

Tags: javascript, date

In the below, `options.min==1969`. Id like to make a new date using `options.min` then call one of the following date functions on that date `.getFullYear(), .getMonth(), .getDay(), .getHours(), .getMinutes()`.

Which function gets called on the new date should depend on the value of `options.type`

I'd like to do this as concisely as possible and avoid repetitive code in `if` and `switch` statements.

THis is my attempt to make this work:

```js
     var options = {
       dateFunctions: {
         years: "getFullYear",
         months: "getMonth",
         days: "getDate",
         hours: "getHours",
         minutes: "getMinutes"
       },
       type: 'days',
       min: '1969-01-02 10:00:00'
     };

     console.log('before: ' + options.min);

     options.min = new Date(options.min)[options.dateFunctions[options.type]]

     console.log('after: ' + options.min);
```

I expect calling `options.min = new Date(options.min)[options.dateFunctions[options.type]]` to be equivalent to calling `new Date('1969-01-02 10:00:00').getDate())` and for `options.min` to be set to `1`.

Instead, `options.min` is set to `function getDate() { [native code] }`

What do I need to change to get the result of the function called on `options.min` instead of the function itself?

Comment: Person who voted to close: Please advise what is unclear about this question, thanks.

Comment: Actually call the function by putting `()` on the end, you're just referencing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function was not called:
Try the direct way:

```
options.min = new Date(options.min)[options.dateFunctions[options.type]]();
```

or via `call` method

```
Date.prototype[options.dateFunctions[options.type]].call(new Date(options.min));
```

Comment: You probably have a typo in `prototype.[`

Answer (score 1):

[There are two ways to access properties in an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). Dot notation and Bracket notation. You're probably looking for the latter.

```
val = object[function_name]();
```

I.e. Just add the parentheses at the end to call the function after you access it.